# Add Cache-control max-age to content pages in ServiceStack but not to dynamic pages

Tags: servicestack

I would like to add a `Cache-Control` header to pages served by ServiceStack Razor, particularly to `/default.cshtml` but not to pages served by ServiceStack Services.

I can use `Response.AddHeader` in `Application_BeginRequest` but I need a way to know which responses are simple content pages and which are dynamically generated using views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them in [PreRequestFilters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations), but why not just add them in the Razor page itself, e.g:

```
@{
    base.Response.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.CacheControl, 
        "max-age=" + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalSeconds);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. I never thought about accesing `base.Response` from the razor page